# HTML Website leaving lots of space at the end

Tags: html, css

I am using a Relative DIV for the entire page but somehow A LOT of space is being left at the end of the page.

For my background, I had used an image but even that image is not that big.
And I've even set the bottom margin to 0px.

http://www.freelancertanish.comli.com

Thanks in advance !

Comment: the calculation of your divs height percentage is more than 100%. It wouldnt be a problem if it was like 50% of the container, but in this case there is no container so its like 1 div 50% + 1 div 50% + 1 div 50% = 150% of the screen height.

Comment: @freestock.tk I believe you are wrong, whenever an element is directly a child of the body, percentages don't get calculated using the screens height. In my experience, they don't get calculated at all. Check out this codepen http://codepen.io/Appie/pen/XdWobG

Comment: But there is only 1 DIV with the image. The rest are sub DIVS and if I add the subdivs, then the total would be over a 1000. So that's not the problem.

Comment: @5parc - That's exactly what I mean.

Comment: @5parc [check this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNWzjm)

Comment: Back to your question, the issue has to do with your background I believe. I think using an image as background when its just a color was a bad idea. Why didn't you just give your body a background of #eeeeee ?

Comment: @freestock.tk But in his case, he isn't using the viewport measurement unit 'vh' neither did he define a width for the body so I think you're wrong.

Comment: I just changed this bunch of divs height and it is fixed.

Comment: Could you please tell me what all you did @freestock.tk Thanks ! :)

Comment: You have **several** divs in a row at your CSS with crazy height like 45%. [**Example**](https://i.gyazo.com/22273d700e97e4a918501cd5b669d56c.png) but check the entire code, theres much more.

Comment: [heres the footer on the bottom after i change the heights for a small value](https://gyazo.com/798931bf12533d3f0cbed2c09184bdf7)

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That really helped :) Cheers. @freestock.tk

Comment: For future reference, I suggest taking a few minutes to review the Help Center, starting with [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Most of the whitespace is there because of `<div id="div-1whiteback">`, which has been given 100% height and positioned down about halfway (adding about half of the page's height again to the bottom). There is additional excess whitespace at the bottom because each of the divs surrounding the logos have been given a specific percentage height which exceeds their allotted space.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot mate ! That really helped ! :) Although I'm still looking for ways to solve it because I do have a few of those divs in my webpage and I can't just delete them.

Comment: The first step would be to kill the `height` attribute in your CSS for each of them so they don't eat up so much room. You'll notice that doing so affects the aspect ratios of the logos (perhaps this is a good thing, so they're less squished?) and then you can align them all to be centered with one another by giving the divs `vertical-align: middle;`!